# Nintegrate error: evaluation of function outside integration region

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to integrate this function with mathematica 9

```
NIntegrate[
 c4[u, v, w] Cos[ 2*w] , {u, -\[Infinity],
   0}, {v, -\[Infinity], u}, {w, -\[Infinity], v]

with
c4[x_, y_, z_] := 
  E^(-((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/
    4 )) (E^((x y)/2 ) + E^((x z)/2 ) + E^((y z)/2));
```

I have this error:

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 27 recursive bisections in v near {u,v,w} = {0.0000318293,2.37147*10^-13,0.0000318293}. NIntegrate obtained -6.039603923653673*10^7640189323695 and 6.039603923653673`15.954589770191005*^7640189323695 for the integral and error estimates. >>

NIntegrate tries to evaluate the integrand outside the integration region. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* it not, rather NIntegrate is internally making a variable substitution to the posivive domain so that the error message is confusing:

Notice if you do this change yourself you get the exact same error message.

```
 NIntegrate[c4[-u, -v, -w] Cos[-2 w], {u, 0, \[Infinity]}, {v,  u, \[Infinity]}, {w, v, \[Infinity]}]
```

If you look what happens with finite bounds:

```
ListPlot[Table[ {s,
  NIntegrate[
   c4[u, v, w] Cos[2 w],
            {u, -s, 0}, 
             {v, -s, u}, 
             {w, -s, v}]} ,   {s, 1, 8, .25}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

I think you'll see this thing is not likely to converge at infinity..

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I have some problems to reproduce your last figure... Mathematica gives me this errors:
NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. [...]

Comment: right, thats why i've only gone to 8, the bigger s gets the harder it is to integrate. (and you want infinity..). Your error messages are slightly different, indicating you probably have a different version of mathematica (9 here).  If you have reason to believe the integral should converge you'll need to do something more sophisticated than direct numerical integration to show it.